# What are the career growth opportunities for an Engineer with Product Testing Experience?

Tags: employment

I studied Medical Engineering and previously worked as a test engineer for flow measuring instruments (for three years now) and find myself in a dead-end job. There are virtually no matching jobs.

While I can program quite well, I can't get a job as a programmer, because the companies prefer "full-fledged" programmers.

Is there an engineering work which is a mixture of Programming and measuring technology | physics | electrical engineering | medical engineering?

For example, PLC and automation technology you can not learn at home apparently. Therefore this is no choice for me.

As an engineer I like logical systems. And I like to improve measurement systems or products. I like programming of course. Therefore automation technology sounds good. But it is difficult to enter this field. Maybe I should apply as an software engineer (C#) and demand less salary.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering SE. Can you please reword your question to something like "What are the career growth opportunities for Engineering with Product Testing Experience? Also try to positive your question body you will have a better chance to get a good response. Note: I was in a similar situation, before I found other options

Comment: I have closed this question as it is more of a discussion than a specific question.  The edits have made it more constructive, but the existing answers and comments are indicative of this being a discussion.  Discussions don't work well for the StackExchange Q&A format but are great fodder for [chat] in The Skunk Works.

Comment: But there are only two people in the chat :/

Comment: @kame - so leave a comment in there and get a conversation started.  You'll need to be patient to see what responses come in.

Comment: I started off as a test engineer. So I give you some suggestion. In order to do that can you please 1) describe your qualification in brief 2) Current industry. 3) Skills acquired since graduation 4) What do really want to as an engineer. Also keep a note on chat I can respond back may Tuesday or Wednesday.

Comment: I need one day to consider this.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, no job is going to be perfect.

Second,  I've been working as an engineer since 1998 and spent all of that time as a test engineer, testing products. I've tested everything from early "let's try it and see" prototypes to testing medical devices during production, maintaining compliance with FDA regulations. I'd say the opportunities now are as good as I've seen them in the past 10 years. I get at least 2 or 3 calls a week from headhunters looking for engineers with a background in product development and testing.

Finally, you have to understand what it is that you offer and sell employers on how your particular set of skills and experiences are a value to them, regardless of what industry you have experience in or what industry the position is in.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Thank you for updating the question. I will update the response appropriately in a few hour (After work) listen to this [Google doesn't care where you went to college](http://money.cnn.com/2015/04/09/technology/google-people-laszlo-bock/)

When most employers seek new employee their are few key points employees pay close attention (I speak for US base companies).

- **Attitude:** Do you have positive attitude?
- **People Skills:** How well does the employee work with peers/co-works
- **Problem Solving Skills:** When confronted with a problem, ability to resolve the problem?
- **Create Business Value:** Does the engineer understand the business value of the engineering problem and can the engineer solve the problem to bring economic value to the company?

As you see all the above have nothing to do with engineering. My best advise is to figure out what you really makes you happy as an engineer (Update your post, so I can modify the answer appropriately), and real your current work experience to your passion. It is all about selling your skills and passion.

If an Engineer has acceptable qualifications and decent work experience then engineer is qualified for the job. Most import thing is when confronted with a engineering problem can the engineer solve the problem to bring economic value to the company. The cold hard truth is if the engineer can create economic value to the company the company will sustain, if the companies sustains, then engineer has more opportunity to follow the engineers passion. There is no magic in this formula.

---

**Reference:**

- [Google doesn't care where you went to college](http://money.cnn.com/2015/04/09/technology/google-people-laszlo-bock/)
- [In Engineering fields, how often do you find yourself being asked to be a “salesperson”, and what is your reaction?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119/in-engineering-fields-how-often-do-you-find-yourself-being-asked-to-be-a-sales)